# how to get multiple items in one line in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have an employees table, which has all the information about employees, including the manager_id, for example:

```
id name manager_id
1  Joe    5 
2  Mary   5
3  Bill   5
4  Jane   6
5  Matt   6
6  Walt   7
```

I would like to get a list of people, and for each one all their direct reports.  Is it possible to create a query to give me the following output:

```
Employee   Direct Reports
Joe
Mary
Bill
Jane
Matt        Joe, Bill, Mary
Walt        Jane, Matt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
SELECT s.name AS employee, group_concat( e.name ) 
FROM employees s
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e ON s.id = e.manager_id
GROUP BY s.id
```

You have to join the table with itself. And you need to use left join, so that you get the employees who don't manage anyone.